# Suitable Kali Mata Mantra for those facing tough times

Tags: shiva, mantras, kali

I am looking for suitable Mata Kali Mantra for those facing tough times and surrounded by people who wish ill (and will do ill when the opportunity strikes) of my family and I.

Just wish to protect from dark forces, and help me focus energies on doing positive, beneficial things (without fear of anything or anyone)

And I've been cautioned that Kali mantras are so effective that many times it may bring (temporary) turmoil in one's life. For instance, if someone is wishing for relationship to work out, Mata Kali may destroy it (and allow you to eventually get a better one).

Do advise suitable Kali Mantra. As it is, I recite Maha Mrityunjaya mantra, 108 times when I awake, 108 times before I sleep. Was told this is great mantra for those who are scared of unknown things (this is me!). It is certainly relaxing, for sure!

Comment: It is not prudent to seek or offer mantras especially mantras such as kaali online. Go to a purohita and seek their advice.